# pointer array in member variable (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

I'm currently struggling with a problem with pointer array member variable, `Addresses`.

The codes below are example codes for my situation. Assume that Addresses always contains at least one element.

```
// MyClass.h

MyClass{
private:
    int size;
    Node* root;
    Node** Addresses; // Node is custom struct
    void saveAddresses(Node* v);
    void UpdateAddresses();
public:
    MyFunction1() {UpdateAddresses(); cout << Addresses[0] << endl;} // cout for debug
    MyFunction2() {UpdateAddresses(); cout << Addresses[0] << endl;} // cout for debug
};
```

```
// MyClass.cpp

void MyClass::saveAddresses(Node* v){
    static int i = 0;
    if (v == nullptr)
        return;
    saveAddresses(v -> left);
    saveAddresses(v -> right);
    Addresses[i++] = v;
    cout << "SAVED: " << v->key << " in " << v << endl;
}

void MyClass::UpdateAddresses(){
    Addresses = new Node*[size];
    saveAddresses(root);
}
```

```
// in main.cpp

MyClass m = MyClass();
m.MyFunction1(); // It works!
m.MyFunction2(); // SEG FAULT!!
```

I confirmed (by using `cout`) that the `saveAddresses()` function normally saves node pointers into `Addresses`. Also, `MyFunction1()` in the main function works well. However, if `MyFunction2()` is called after function call `MyFunction1()`, a `segmentation fault` occurs(`Addresses[]` becomes `nullptr` here). I really don't know what the problem is. Please help me!

Note: `std::vector` is prohibited.

Comment: use `std::vector`

Comment: A side note: `UpdateAddresses` does not free the previous data before reassiging the pointer. This will cause a memory leak.

Comment: you never set root yo nullptr

Comment: @pm100 I cannot use vector because the use of STL is prohibited for some reason.

Comment: @wohlstad This code is simplified version of my code, so I skip that part.

Comment: ilovespotify show this to your teacher : https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly and tell him std::vector is the datastructure to use. It wouldn't change your assignment a lot, unless he is out to show you that using new/delete manually will lead to memory leaks. I write a lot of datastructurs/infrastructures and I hardly ever have to use new/delete. I'd be happy to have a discussion with him :)

Comment: @PepijnKramer I will share your recommendations with the professor. But I'm so curious why my code doesn't work.

Comment: @ilovespotify To what value to you set `size`?

Comment: @PepijnKramer: I will not follow you on that path. For real worls programs, `std::vector` is of course be the way to go. But when teaching beginners, it may be interesting to show them how the (not so) good old C-ish arrays have to be handled, to later explain what the standard library containers are and *show* the reason to always use them. Sometimes it is better to show than to just say... (Disclaimer I am **not** OP's teacher ;-) )

Comment: We really need a [mre] to tell you where the problem is. You do not show how `root` and `size` are initialized so we cannot guess if `saveAddresses` can write past end of the allocated array. It that happens, you will invoke Undefined Behaviour, and weird things **are** to be expected...

Comment: "I cannot use vector because" *then roll your own simplified vector*. Really, there's no reason not to.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Ok different teaching styles I guess. When I mentor people I usually set things up for a first positive experience. Showing them how to use existing datastructures so they first make working programs which brings its own kind of joy. Then dive into the details. Exagarating a bit here : following your path we should first teach assembly :) So we can agree to disagree here, just different approaches

Comment: @SergeBallesta Or to put differently it makes a lot of difference whether you are trying to teach "C++" or if you are teaching students about "datastructures using C++". And in the second case I still would teach the standard library (use of datastructures) before implementation of datastructurs. Since students tend to use what they learned first (and that should not be write your own datastructures from scratch all time).

Answer (score 0):

Your `UpdateAddresses` function will create a new array everytime it is called. If you call it twice, it will always call `saveAddresses` with a single Node, but the counter will always increased. I see two problems with that:

1. I don't know what set `size` to, but it could be that on the second call of `saveAddresses` you try to set the value for index 1, but it the array is too small (just guessing here).
2. The first time you call `saveAddresses`, it will save the node to index 0, which is also the one you read from. The second time you will save the node to index 1, but you will try to read from index 0, which is not initialized.